# VS Code Update Error / inno_updater.exe - application error

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I closed the program(vs code), I saw this Error dialog message.

> inno_updater.exe - Application Error

My computer and program's information is that:

OS : Windows 8.1 Pro K 64bit (6.3, build 9600)

VS code version : 1.64.2 (16 March 2022)

I tried to solve this problem on Google and You tube.

I check the DirectX version.

DirectX version : DirectX11

And then, I check the latest version from the direct end user website.

However I restart my computer at many times, I can't find what is the problem.

I hope someone helps me~

Already I appreciated your kindness ~~~

Comment: This might be the wrong forum.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I knew that that question is not appropriated in this forum. But, I can't find the solution about the problem. And, finally I launched the OS (win10) . And then, I can solve the problem. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to download the newest version of vscode and when the installer is asking you for the install directory, there is prepopulated install path 
[something/something/Microsoft VS Code],
change it to  
[something/something/Microsoft VS Code2(or whatever)] and it will probably work.

this is how I salvaged the situation :)